# Why does cmake always use `-isystem` on imported interface target?

Tags: gcc, cmake, include-path, avr-gcc, compiler-flags

I'm trying to write a CMakeLists.txt to compile my Arduino-Projects to get to know cmake better.
I defined the Arduino-Core library as an imported interface and try to link my own target against it. The problem is, that, when calling `make` the avr-gcc is provided with the specified include-paths via `-isystem` instead of `-I`. This results in several errors.

CMakeLists.txt (minimal-version to reproduce the problem)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
set(ARDUINO_DIR "/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.13")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${ARDUINO_DIR}/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${ARDUINO_DIR}/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME NONE)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR NONE)

add_library(Arduino::Core INTERFACE IMPORTED)
target_include_directories(Arduino::Core INTERFACE 
  "${ARDUINO_DIR}/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/"
  "${ARDUINO_DIR}/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/eightanaloginputs/"
)
file(GLOB_RECURSE ARDUINO_CORE_SRC "${ARDUINO_DIR}/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/*.c[p]*")
file(GLOB_RECURSE ARDUINO_CORE_ASM "${ARDUINO_DIR}/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/*.S")
target_sources(Arduino::Core INTERFACE ${ARDUINO_CORE_SRC} ${ARDUINO_CORE_ASM})
project(Blinky)

set(${PROJECT_NAME}_SRC
  src/Blink.cpp
)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SRC})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Arduino::Core)
```

Here is my Blink.cpp:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
void setup()
{
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  delay(1000);
}
```

`make --trace` gives me the following output:

```
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Blinky.dir/src/Blink.cpp.obj
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.13/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++  -isystem     /opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.13/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -isystem /opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.13/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/eightanaloginputs -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/Blinky.dir/src/Blink.cpp.obj -c /tmp/so/src/Blink.cpp
```

As you can see, linking against the imported target includes the dependencies with `-isystem` even though I haven't declared `SYSTEM` anywhere? How can I prevent that?!
Is it, because it is an `INTERFACE IMPORTED` target?
I tried `taget_include_directories(Arduino::Core PRIVATE ${my_include_dirs})` but obviously that is not allowed for `INTERFACE`-Targets.

Thanks in advance for every hint.

P.S. please note, that I'm aware, that this would not compile my arduino-code. This is just a mcve to show you my problem.

*edit*

I'm using Arduino-SDK 1.8.13 and cmake 3.18.2

Comment: `As you can see, linking against the imported target includes the dependencies with -isystem` I think, I do not see that. Where should I see that? Did you forgot to post the verbose build output? `I haven't declared SYSTEM anywhere` It's right there in `target_include_directories(Arduino::Core SYSTEM`, no?

Comment: I'm sorry. The `SYSTEM` was a leftover from previous trial-and-error approaches.
I'll update the question

Comment: Are you sure that given include directories come from the **linking** with `Arduino::Core` and not from the **compiler detection** procedure? BTW, instead of INTERFACE IMPORTED library *with sources* it will be simpler to use OBJECT library. And normally `project()` call should preceed all `add_library` calls (though CMake could "fix" that order in some cases).

Comment: Variables like `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` or `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` should normally be set in the toolchain file, not in the `CMakeLists.txt`. The same for `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` variables, though they could also be set in the command line.

Comment: No I'm not. As I wrote I try to deepen my understandings of cmake with this "project". But if I comment out `target_link_libraries`, the includes disappear (so I assumed that).

My "real" project consists of a ToolchainFile and a a FindArduino.cmake-Module (in which the `Arduino::Core`-Target is defined. If that'll help, I can post it on github. As I said, I tried to compress everything together to show you guys my specific problem

Comment: According to the suggestion to use `OBJECT` library: I don't understand how that should work. Therefore that I create that target (as a component) within `FindArduino.cmake` I get an cmake-error, when I change the library type from `INTERFACE` to `OBJECT`: `Cannot specify include directories for target "Arduino::Core" which is not built by this project`
So I'd like to keep it as `INTERFACE IMPORTED` before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because it is an imported target.

From the [CMake docs on buildsystems at the section for "include directories and usage requirements"](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#include-directories-and-usage-requirements) (one of the last paragraphs in the section):

> When the [`INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html) of an [imported target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets) is consumed, the entries in the property are treated as `SYSTEM` include directories, as if they were listed in the [`INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html) of the dependency. This can result in omission of compiler warnings for headers found in those directories. This behavior for Imported Targets may be controlled by setting the [`NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED.html) target property on the consumers of imported targets, or by setting the IMPORTED_NO_SYSTEM target property on the imported targets themselves.

See the docs for [`include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html) and [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) for other documentation on `SYSTEM`.

As stated in the docs, you can solve this by modifying *consumers* of the imported target like `set_target_property(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED TRUE)` or `set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED TRUE)`.

But there's another option not mentioned in the docs I quoted that I think may be better: In the docs for `NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED`, it says:

> See the [`IMPORTED_NO_SYSTEM`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_NO_SYSTEM.html) target property to set this behavior on the target providing the include directories rather than consuming them.

I think it's better because `NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED` will change the "system-ness" of all imported targets that the consumer links to, which may not be desirable. Perhaps a similar argument could be made against `IMPORTED_NO_SYSTEM`, but I personally can't think of a good backing for such an argument at the moment.